# Escaping '{' when regex-ing in java?

Tags: java, regex, bufferedreader

I'm trying to get my code to ignore some some lines it's reading. My SSCE is thus:

```
public class testRegex {
    private static final String DELETE_REGEX = "\\{\"delete"; //escape the '{', escape the ' " '
    private static final String JSON_FILE_NAME = "example";
public static void main(String[] args){
    String line = null;
    try{
        BufferedReader buff = new BufferedReader (new FileReader(JSON_FILE_NAME + ".json"));
        line = buff.readLine        buff.close();
        }catch (FileNotFoundException e){e.printStackTrace();}
         catch (IOException e){e.printStackTrace();}
    String line=buff.readLine();
    System.out.println(line.contains(DELETE_REGEX));
    }
}
```

My file only contains the line:

`{"delete":{"status":{"user_id_str":"123456789","user_id":123456789,"id_str":"987654321","id":987654321}}}`

But this prints out false...is my regex wrong? I'm matching `{` by double escaping it with `\\{` as it advises [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum).

> The string literal `"\(hello\)"` is illegal and leads to a compile-time error; in order to match the string (hello) the string literal `"\\(hello\\)"` must be used.

And I escape the `"` by using `\"`.

So how can I fix my program?

*p.s. I've tried manually inputting `line = "\{\"delete"` (no need to double escape as line is a string not a regex), and I get the same result.

Comment: How come you're "double escaping" the brace and not the quotes?

Comment: I've managed to find a different regex that should work in all but the oddest circumstances, but I'd still like to know why this doesn't work...

Comment: @Phillip `{` is a special regex character, for instance `X{n}` means '*find X, n times*', and `"` isn't (if it was I think Java would shout at me)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [contains](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) method doesn't take a regex as parameter so you don't have to escape the `{`.

Simply do

```
line.contains("{\"delete")
```

Comment: 23 seconds late! But I think a much better explanation.

Comment: 23 seconds late because I took the time to link to the doc. But that's the game and I don't always lose ;)

Answer (score 6):

String.contains() performs an exact match, not a regex search. Do not escape the { brace.

Comment: Nice catch. I didn't even notice he was doing a `Contains()`

Comment: Or use `String.matches(regex)`, if you need a regex.

Comment: It works! @verdesmarald I've tried `matches`, but I get an 'illegal repetition' PatternSyntaxErrorException with my `regex = "{\"delete"`. `"{\"delete"` is not allowed and `"\\{\"delete"` doesn't catch it with `match`.

Comment: @Pureferret `String.matches()` matches the whole string, so you would have to use `"\\{\"delete.*"`. If you want to search for a subsequence you can use [`Matcher.find()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find()).